# Configuration file in spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a base configuration file in **Spring MVC** using Maven.

All Documentations/tutorials around the internet seem to use `@Value` or  `@ConfigurationProperties`, but these are Spring boot related.

Any clean way to that in pure Spring? 
Should I be using Spring boot?

Comment: Check this http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 1):

The `@Value` annotation is no SpringBoot element. You can use it in combination with `@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")`.

Example:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class SomeClass {

    @Value("${some.value}")
    private String someValue;
    ...
}
```